# Using WPF-GUI with WindowsPE

Tags: wpf, windows, powershell, winpe

I wanted to use a WPF-GUI for my powershell-script that is executed in a WIndowsPE enviroment.

When I start the script the GUI opens but closes/crashes after a few seconds.
I already read that there is no support for WPF, however I found a [fix](https://msendpointmgr.com/2018/11/23/fix-windows-adk-version-1809-issue-with-crashing-wpf-applications/) from someone that seemed to have the same problem. After implementing the fix nothing changed and my GUI still crashes.

Is there a way to use WPF with WindowsPE?

I could use WInForms but I would rather not since I can´t create multiple tabs for example.

Maybe someone can help me out.

Comment: "I can't create multiple tabs in winforms" - why not? https://www.google.com/search?q=create+multiple+tabs+winforms

Comment: did you publish your WPF as a stand-alone executable? I'm running a WPF application in WinPE and it works fine.
Did you add these packages to your WinPE environment?
[How can I get an application to run in WinPE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67697322/how-can-i-get-an-application-to-run-in-winpe)

Comment: I implemented it as a the Update.ps1 file, it works with winforms.